# What is the correct placement order of these lines of code in PHP?

Tags: php

Can anyone please tell me the correct placement order of the function calls below (assuming we put all these calls in a single script file):

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Does the order really matter in this case, or is it pointless?

Comment: All of these do completely different things and one should not affect the other in any way. So order does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these particular function calls, it truly doesn't matter.

`session_start()` needs to run before any output occurs. As you're enabling Output Buffering, this won't matter much.

The `ini_set()` can happen at any time, but will only apply to commands executed after the `ini_set()`.

So, as I said, it doesn't matter, but here's how I would order them and why.

```
<?php
// We do this first, because this involves configuration of the
// PHP interpreter itself.
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

// This comes next, because it initializes a shared framework that
// the  rest of the code will use.
session_start();

// This only has to do with output buffering, so we do this last.
// It's scope of action is smaller than the other function calls.
ob_start();
```

Comment: Ok I understand what you explained here. Thanks @Will

Comment: No problem, glad to help!